# Create nattable with two column ,the second column has multiple dynamic rows inside

Tags: java, swt, jface, nattable

I am trying to  create a table in `NatTable` that has two columns.
The first column is straight-forward but I need help while creating the second one.
Each cell of the second column has to have a dynamic number of rows, like in the image provided. In other words, each cell of the second column is divided into a variable number of rows.
I am using `NatTable` because of it's capacity to handle large data. But any solution is good at this point. (JFace etc)

[This is what I am trying to achieve (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gByXj.png)

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using the `TableCellPainter`. A description with an example is contained here: https://eclipse.org/nattable/nandn/nandn_110.php